# ¿cómo obtener el id del último registro de una tabla y utilizarlo para hacer registros subsecuentes en otras tablas?

Tags: php, base-de-datos

[image: Página de creación de proyectos]

Buen día.

> **Mi problema es el siguiente:**
>
> Deseo crear múltiples registros a través de los formularios dinámicos
>   (lista de materiales y actividades) que tengan como id, el id del
>   formulario estático "proyecto" (que está compuesto por el apartado de
>   información, tiempo total y costo total).  Cada formulario se guarda
>   en una tabla diferente en una misma base de datos al dar clic en el
>   botón "save" (primero se guarda el formulario estático "proyecto").
>
> **Mi pregunta es:**
>
> ¿Cómo puedo recoger el último id del formulario estático "proyecto" y
>   utilizarlo como el id de mis "n" materiales y/o actividades que yo
>   agregue en mis formularios dinámicos "lista de materiales" y
>   "actividades" al darle clic en el botón "save"? Esto con la finalidad
>   de que el id de las actividades y materiales me indique a cuál
>   proyecto pertenecen.

Agradezco muchísimo la atención.

Les comparto mis códigos (siéntanse con la libertad de utilizarlos si les es de utilidad):

**Código ajax (el que guarda el texto capturado en los tres formularios en las tablas de la base de datos):**

```
    $('#save').click(function(){
  var nombre_proyecto = [];
  var descripcion_proyecto = [];
  var supervisor_proyecto = [];
  var tiempo_proyecto = [];
  var costo_proyecto = [];
  $('.nombre_proyecto').each(function(){
   nombre_proyecto.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.descripcion_proyecto').each(function(){
   descripcion_proyecto.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.supervisor_proyecto').each(function(){
   supervisor_proyecto.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.tiempo_proyecto').each(function(){
   tiempo_proyecto.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.costo_proyecto').each(function(){
   costo_proyecto.push($(this).text());
  });
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert3.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{nombre_proyecto:nombre_proyecto, descripcion_proyecto:descripcion_proyecto, supervisor_proyecto:supervisor_proyecto, tiempo_proyecto:tiempo_proyecto, costo_proyecto:costo_proyecto},
   success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
    for(var i=2; i<= count; i++)
    {
     $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
    }
   }
  });
 });

 function fetch_item_data()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#inserted_item_data').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
 fetch_item_data();

 $('#save').click(function(){
  var item_name = [];
  var item_code = [];
  var item_desc = [];
  var item_price = [];
  var item_time = [];
  $('.item_name').each(function(){
   item_name.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_code').each(function(){
   item_code.push($(this).list());
  });
  $('.item_desc').each(function(){
   item_desc.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_price').each(function(){
   item_price.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_time').each(function(){
   item_time.push($(this).text());
  });
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert2.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{item_name:item_name, item_code:item_code, item_desc:item_desc, item_price:item_price, item_time:item_time},
   success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
    for(var i=2; i<= count; i++)
    {
     $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
    }
   }
  });
 });

 function fetch_item_data()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#inserted_item_data').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
 fetch_item_data();

});


 $('#save').click(function(){
  var item_act = [];
  var item_tipo = [];
  var item_desca = [];
  var item_timea = [];
  var item_respa = [];
  $('.item_act').each(function(){
   item_act.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_tipo').each(function(){
   item_tipo.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_desca').each(function(){
   item_desca.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_timea').each(function(){
   item_timea.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_respa').each(function(){
   item_respa.push($(this).text());
  });
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{item_act:item_act, item_tipo:item_tipo, item_desca:item_desca, item_timea:item_timea, item_respa:item_respa},
   success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
    for(var i=2; i<= count; i++)
    {
     $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
    }
    fetch_item_data();
   }
  });
 });

 function fetch_item_data()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#inserted_item_data').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
});
</script>
```

**Código PHP (el que hace la conexión con la bd y realiza la inserción en las tablas) utilizo un código php para cada formulario:**

```
 <?php
//insert.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
if(isset($_POST["item_act"]))
{
 $item_act = $_POST["item_act"];
 $item_tipo = $_POST["item_tipo"];
 $item_desca = $_POST["item_desca"];
 $item_timea = $_POST["item_timea"];
 $item_respa = $_POST["item_respa"];
 $query = '';
 for($count = 0; $count<count($item_act); $count++)
 {
  $item_act_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_act[$count]);
  $item_tipo_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_tipo[$count]);
  $item_desca_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_desca[$count]);
  $item_timea_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_timea[$count]);
  $item_respa_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_respa[$count]);
  if($item_act_clean != '' && $item_tipo_clean != '' && $item_desca_clean != '' && $item_timea_clean != '' && $item_respa_clean != '')
  {
   $query .= '
   INSERT INTO item(item_act, item_tipo, item_desca, item_timea, item_respa) 
   VALUES("'.$item_act_clean.'", "'.$item_tipo_clean.'", "'.$item_desca_clean.'", "'.$item_timea_clean.'", "'.$item_respa_clean.'"); 
   ';
  }
 }
 if($query != '')
 {
  if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query))
  {
   echo 'Item Data Inserted';
  }
  else
  {
   echo 'Error';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'All Fields are Required';
 }
}
?>

<?php
//insert2.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
if(isset($_POST["item_name"]))
{
 $item_name = $_POST["item_name"];
 $item_code = $_POST["item_code"];
 $item_desc = $_POST["item_desc"];
 $item_price = $_POST["item_price"];
 $item_time = $_POST["item_time"];
 $query = '';
 for($count = 0; $count<count($item_name); $count++)
 {
  $item_name_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_name[$count]);
  $item_code_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_code[$count]);
  $item_desc_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_desc[$count]);
  $item_price_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_price[$count]);
  $item_time_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $item_time[$count]);
  if($item_name_clean != '' && $item_code_clean != '' && $item_desc_clean != '' && $item_price_clean != '' && $item_time_clean != '')
  {
   $query .= '
   INSERT INTO item2(item_name, item_code, item_desc, item_price, item_time) 
   VALUES("'.$item_name_clean.'", "'.$item_code_clean.'", "'.$item_desc_clean.'", "'.$item_price_clean.'", "'.$item_time_clean.'"); 
   ';
  }
 }
 if($query != '')
 {
  if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query))
  {
   echo 'Item Data Inserted';
  }
  else
  {
   echo 'Error';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'All Fields are Required';
 }
}
?>

<?php
//insert3.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
if(isset($_POST["nombre_proyecto"]))
{
 $nombre_proyecto = $_POST["nombre_proyecto"];
 $descripcion_proyecto = $_POST["descripcion_proyecto"];
 $supervisor_proyecto = $_POST["supervisor_proyecto"];
 $tiempo_proyecto = $_POST["tiempo_proyecto"];
 $costo_proyecto = $_POST["costo_proyecto"];
 $query = '';
 for($count = 0; $count<count($nombre_proyecto); $count++)
 {
  $nombre_proyecto_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $nombre_proyecto[$count]);
  $descripcion_proyecto_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $descripcion_proyecto[$count]);
  $supervisor_proyecto_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $supervisor_proyecto[$count]);
  $tiempo_proyecto_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $tiempo_proyecto[$count]);
  $costo_proyecto_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $costo_proyecto[$count]);
  if($nombre_proyecto_clean != '' && $descripcion_proyecto_clean != '' && $supervisor_proyecto_clean != '' && $tiempo_proyecto_clean != '' && $costo_proyecto_clean != '')
  {
   $query .= '
   INSERT INTO item3(nombre_proyecto, descripcion_proyecto, supervisor_proyecto, tiempo_proyecto, costo_proyecto) 
   VALUES("'.$nombre_proyecto_clean.'", "'.$descripcion_proyecto_clean.'", "'.$supervisor_proyecto_clean .'", "'.$tiempo_proyecto_clean.'", "'.$costo_proyecto_clean.'"); 
   ';
  }
 }
 if($query != '')
 {
  if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query))
  {
   echo 'Item Data Inserted';
  }
  else
  {
   echo 'Error';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'All Fields are Required';
 }
}
?>
```

**Código HTML:**

```
    <div id="barra_lateral">
    <div id="contenedor_foto">
      <div id="contenedor_home"><a href="welcome.php" title="Home"><center><strong>Home</strong></center></a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="contenedor_rango"></div>
  <div id="contenedor_menus">
    <div id="menu_au">
        <div id="titulo_menu_au">Administrador de usuarios</div>
        <div id="submenu_au">
            <ul id=”administrador_usuarios”>
                <li><a href=registro_usuarios.php>Registrar usuario</a></li>
                 <li><a href="modificar_usuarios.php">Modficar usuario</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Eliminar usuario</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu_descargas">
      <div id="titulo_menu_descargas">Descargas</div>
      <div id="submenu_descargas">
            <ul id=”administrador_usuarios”>
                <li><a href="#">Proyectos</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Rendimiento</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="encabezado_gris">
    <div id="titulo_cproyectos"><strong>Creacion de proyectos</strong></div>
  </div>
  <div id="encabezado_azul"></div>
  <div id="encabezado_verde">
    <div id="contenedor_guardar">
    <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="zona_info">
    <div id="titulo_informacion"><strong>Informacion</strong></div>
    <div id="nombre_proyecto">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla_nombre">
        <th width="15%" height="15%" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">Nombre</th>
        <td height="15%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="nombre_proyecto"></td>
     </table>
    </div>
    <div id="descripcion_proyecto">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla_descripcion">
        <th width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><center>Descripcion</center></th>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="descripcion_proyecto"></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     </div>
    <div id="supervisor_asignado">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla_supervisor">
        <th width="15%" height="100%" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><center>Supervisor</center></th>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="supervisor_proyecto"></td>
     </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="zona_material">
    <div id="titulo_materiales"><strong>Lista de materiales</strong></div>
        <div id="contenedor_lmateriales">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="crud_table">
             <tr>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Material</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Responsable</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Descripcion</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Costo</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Tiempo</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="5%">Acciones</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_name"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_code"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_desc"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_price"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_time"></td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" >+</button></td>
             </tr>
            </table>

       </div>
  </div>
<div id="zona_tiempo">
    <div id="titulo_tiempo"><strong><center>Tiempo total</center></strong></div>
    <div id="tiempo">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla_supervisor">
        <th width="15%" height="100%" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><center>Tiempo</center></th>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="tiempo_proyecto"></td>
     </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="zona_costo">
    <div id="titulo_costo"><strong><center>Costo total</center></strong></div>
    <div id="costo">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla_supervisor">
        <th width="15%" height="100%" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><center>Costo</center></th>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="costo_proyecto"></td>
     </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="zona_actividades">
    <div id="titulo_actividades"><strong>Actividades</strong></div>
<div id="contenedor_lactividades">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="crud_tablea">
             <tr>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Actividad</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Tipo</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Descripcion</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Tiempo</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="15%">Responsable</th>
              <th bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="5%">Acciones</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_act"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_tipo"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_desca"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_timea"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" class="item_respa"></td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F0F0F0"><button type="button" name="adda" id="adda" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" >+</button></td>
             </tr>
            </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Código AJAX que agrega/elimina campos en los formularios dinámicos:**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
 var count = 1;
 $('#add').click(function(){
  count = count + 1;
  var html_code = "<tr id='row"+count+"'>";
   html_code += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_name'></td>";
   html_code += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_code'></td>";
   html_code += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_desc'></td>";
   html_code += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_price' ></td>";
   html_code += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_time' ></td>";
   html_code += "<td bgcolor='#F0F0F0' valign='middle' align='center'><button type='button' name='remove' data-row='row"+count+"' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove'>-</button></td>";   
   html_code += "</tr>";  
   $('#crud_table').append(html_code);
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  var delete_row = $(this).data("row");
  $('#' + delete_row).remove();
 });

 $(document).ready(function(){
 var count = 1;
 $('#adda').click(function(){
  count = count + 1;
  var html_codea = "<tr id='row"+count+"'>";
   html_codea += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_act'></td>";
   html_codea += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_tipo'></td>";
   html_codea += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_desca'></td>";
   html_codea += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_timea' ></td>";
   html_codea += "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' contenteditable='true' class='item_respa' ></td>";
   html_codea += "<td bgcolor='#F0F0F0' valign='middle' align='center'><button type='button' name='remove' data-row='row"+count+"' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove'>-</button></td>";   
   html_codea += "</tr>";  
   $('#crud_tablea').append(html_codea);
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  var delete_row = $(this).data("row");
  $('#' + delete_row).remove();
 });
```

Comment: En base a lo que logro entender, quieres tomar el ultimo id insertado y usarlo para insertarlo en otro tabla para decirle que esas actividades y materiales pertenecen a ese proyecto?
Si tu id es un auto_increment puedes usar **mysql_insert_id()**

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, Ricardo. Así es, es justamente lo que busco. La situación es que no sé exactamente donde poner "mysql_insert_id()" dentro de todo mi código y hacer que esto funcione de tal manera que, así yo agregue cien actividades y materiales en los formularios dinámicos, en cada uno de estos registros se tome el id del proyecto. ¿Me podrías orientar, por favor?

Comment: Despues del insert a la tabla de proyectos(creo que es item3) asigna la variable así $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect); en base a la documentación oficial de [PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-insert-id.php)